# delete repeated following words in an array

Tags: c

I got assignment to check string and to see if there is repeated words inside it

for example
Source string: this is is a test test.

changes to: this is a test.

```
void RemoveDuplicates(char *fixst) {
    char tempstr[N];
    char *subst = NULL;
    *tempstr = 0;
    subst = strtok(fixst, " ");
    if ((subst != NULL) && strstr(tempstr, subst) == NULL)
    {
        strcpy(tempstr, subst);
        while ((subst = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) 
        {
            if (strstr(tempstr, subst) == NULL) 
            {
                strcat(tempstr, " ");
                strcat(tempstr, subst);
            }
        }
    }
    strcpy(fixst, tempstr);
}
```

This is my code and the output that i'm getting is: this a test

As you can see the word 'is' deleted.

Another String: this is a test test to to this class.

Changes to: this a test to class.

Expected output: this is a test to this class.

Also delete the word 'is' and 'this'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please fix the formatting.

Comment: Seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please read this: Why should I provide a [mcve]

Comment: You're testing whether the next word, `subst`, is in the *whole* of the new string (`tempstr`). You should be checking whether it is the same as the previous word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple algorithm below iterates over each token / word in the input character array. When it finds a new token / word, it will copy it to the output string if either:

- it is the very first token, or
- it differs from the last token

A pointer to the previous token is updated within each iteration of the loop - to facilitate the comparison.

```c
void remove_duplicate_words(char *input) {
    size_t input_len = strlen(input);
    char *result = (char *)malloc(input_len + 1);
    if (!result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!");
        return;
    }
    char *last_word = NULL;
    char *word = strtok(input, " ");

    while (word) {
        // Is this either the first word or different from the last word?
        if (last_word == NULL || strcmp(word, last_word) != 0) {
            // Yes -> append it to the output array
            strcat(result, word);
            strcat(result, " ");
        }
        last_word = word;
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    puts(result);

    free(result);
}
```

Notes:

- I used different variable names to those in your example - opting for ones which I think more clearly convey their meaning.
- The memory for the output array (`result`) is allocated dynamically - based on the length of the input string. (We know it can't be longer than the input array).